# Uncaught PHP Exception PDOException SQLSTATE[25P02]: In failed sql transaction - writing duplicate session entries in SF2 application

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, session, pdo

I am experiencing an issue with an edge case scenario in my application. I say it is an edge case because I cannot replicate it and when analyzing the context in the error logs there is no pattern or consistency to when the errors occur.

The error I get is:

> 2016-07-10 07:18:43.418 {"message":"[2016-07-10 15:18:41]
>   request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception PDOException:
>   \"SQLSTATE[25P02]: In failed sql transaction: 7 ERROR:  current
>   transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction
>   block\" at
>   /var/www/crmpicco/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php
>   line 546 {\"exception\":\" [object] (PDOException(code: 25P02):
>   SQLSTATE[25P02]: In failed sql transaction: 7 ERROR:  current
>   transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction
>   block at
>   /var/www/crmpicco/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php:546)\"}

I am using Symfony 2.7.6, PostgreSQL 9.4.8 and it is hosted on Amazon AWS.

[This is the line](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/v2.7.6/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php#L546) it is erroring on which looks very similar to the version of `PdoSessionHandler.php` that I have below in my app:

`/var/www/html/crmpicco/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php`:

```
// Exclusive-reading of non-existent rows does not block, so we need to do an insert to block
// until other connections to the session are committed.
try {
    $insertStmt = $this->pdo->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO $this->table ($this->idCol, $this->dataCol, $this->lifetimeCol, $this->timeCol) VALUES (:id, :data, :lifetime, :time)"
    );
    $insertStmt->bindParam(':id', $sessionId, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insertStmt->bindValue(':data', '', \PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $insertStmt->bindValue(':lifetime', 0, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $insertStmt->bindValue(':time', time(), \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $insertStmt->execute();
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    // Catch duplicate key error because other connection created the session already.
    // It would only not be the case when the other connection destroyed the session.
    if (0 === strpos($e->getCode(), '23')) {
        // Retrieve finished session data written by concurrent connection. SELECT
        // FOR UPDATE is necessary to avoid deadlock of connection that starts reading
        // before we write (transform intention to real lock).
        $selectStmt->execute();
        $sessionRows = $selectStmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        if ($sessionRows) {
            return is_resource($sessionRows[0][0]) ? stream_get_contents($sessionRows[0][0]) : $sessionRows[0][0];
        }

        return '';
    }

    throw $e;
}
```

I have deduced that this is caused by a duplicate key value violation, however debugging Symfony session issues seems to be arduous and difficult.

```
2016-07-21 02:52:03 UTC:10.40.211.49(51840):crmpicco@crmpicco:[15647]:ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "sessions_pkey"
2016-07-21 02:52:03 UTC:10.40.211.49(51840):crmpicco@crmpicco:[15647]:DETAIL: Key (sess_id)=(8kmn7dj5dbqkjhp7mu8pq6i544) already exists.
2016-07-21 02:52:03 UTC:10.40.211.49(51840):crmpicco@crmpicco:[15647]:STATEMENT: INSERT INTO sessions (sess_id, sess_data, sess_lifetime, sess_time) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
```

Comment: The error message states the `INSERT` query is rejected because the transaction is already in a failed state. Your option is to found out why a statement is rejected without notice.

Comment: @greg I don't understand your comment. The failure is the `INSERT` into the `sessions` table which appears to be a failure because the key already exists in the table. The statement isn't rejected without notice it is causing a HTTP 500 error and I am trying to solve it.

Comment: So, why does the error message be «SQLSTATE[25P02]: In failed sql transaction: 7 ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block.» This message is raised when a transaction is in failed state and queries are still issued.

Comment: @greg Herein lies the challenge. I can't for the life of me work out how to find that transaction - why does Symfony not report the transaction that failed?

Comment: Check the logs of PostgreSQL. It should log the failing queries. The first that fails may be the one.